# What's the equivalent of C's "static" keyword in Java?

Tags: java, c, static

I want to know what could be the equivalent keyword in java which could perform same function as "Static keyword in C".. I want to do recursion in java, performing same function that a static keyword in C does...

Please help..

Comment: I know you're probably being polite, but you don't have to thank us all individually :-) It probably would have been okay (and easier for you) to just put a general thanks in this comment area.

Answer (score 38):

C has two entirely different uses of the `static` keyword, and C++ adds a third use:

```
// Use 1: declare a variable or function to be local to a given module
// At global scope:
static int global_var;
static void func();
```

In this case, the global variable `global_var` and the function `void func()` can only be accessed inside the file in which they are declared; they cannot be accessed by any other file.

```
// Use 2: declare a variable inside a function with global scope
void func(void)
{
    static int x;
}
```

In this case, the variable `x` is effectively a global variable, in that there is only one instance of it -- multiple calls to `func()` (including recursive calls) will always access the same variable.

```
// Use 3 (C++ only): declare a global variable with class scope
class Widget
{
public:
    static int var;
};
```

In this case, this declares the variable `Widget::var` as a global variable, but its scope is different.  Outside of class member functions, it has to be named as `Widget::var`; inside class member functions, it can be named as just `var`.  It can also be made `protected` or `private` to limit its scope even more.

Now, what are the analogs of these 3 uses in Java?

Case 1 has no direct analog; the closest is declaring objects with package scope, which is done by omitting a `public`, `protected`, or `private`:

```
class Widget  // Declare a class with package scope
{
    int x;  // Declare a member variable with package scope
    void func() {}  // Declare a member function with package scope
}
```

In this case, the declared objects are only accessible by classes within the same package; they are not accessible to other packages.

Case 2 also does not have an analog in Java.  The closest you can get is by declaring a global variable (that is, a static class variable, since Java doesn't have true global variables in the strictest sense):

```
class Widget
{
    private static int func_x;
    public static void func()
    {
        // use func_x here in place of 'static int x' in the C example
    }
}
```

Case 3 is the only case that has a *direct* analog in Java.  In this case, the `static` keyword serves exactly the same purpose.

Comment: Wait, I thought use #2 also existed in Java, in that declaring a variable as `static` will allow its value to persist between calls to the function. It's been so long since I've used Java that I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Bunch of unnecessary info dump. The OP doesn't even mention C++ and they are pretty clear about which variant of  `static` in C they need. All that's required was Case 2 of this answer. Keep it to the point.

Answer (score 10):

The `"static"` keyword in C actually serves two functions depending on where it's used. Those functions are visibility and duration (these are my terms based on quite a bit of teaching, the standard, if you're interested in that level of detail, uses different terms which I often find confuses new students, hence my reticence in using them).

- When used at file level, it marks an item (variable or function) as non-exported so that a linker cannot see it. This is static as in visibility, duration is the same as the program (i.e., until the program exits). This is useful for encapsulating the item within a single compilation unit (a source file, in its simplest definition). The item is available to the whole compilation unit (assuming it's declared before use).
- When used within a function, it controls duration (visibility is limited to within the function). In this case, the item is also created once and endures until the program exits. Non-static variables within a function are created and destroyed on function entry and exit.

I gather what you're after is the first type, basically a global variable since I can't immediately see much of a use for the other variant in recursion..

It can't be done since, in Java, *everything* must belong to a class. The workaround is to create a class holding the "globals" and either:

- pass that object around so you can reference its members; or
- construct a singleton item so you can access its members.

Answer (score 5):

Java doesn't have global variables, so there isn't a direct equivalent. However, there's a `static` keyword in Java that shares the state of a field with all instances of a class, which is a good approximation to what you're describing.

> I want to do recursion in java, performing same function that a static keyword in C does...

However, if you're looking to do recursion, **are you sure that static variables are what you need?** Any special state needed for a recursive function call is almost always passed back to itself, not maintained separately.

Comment: What John mentioned seems absolutely true, I doubt the use of static variable in recursive function. It would be clean if you can write the  recursive function as well ...

Comment: No problem. If you have another question about recursive functions, do go ahead and ask that one too.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of *static* in Java doesn't adhere with the concept of *static* in C. However, there is a *static* keyword in Java as well. But its more like a *static* in C++ then C, with some differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a static class in java as follows:

```
   /**
     * Utility class: this class contains only static methods and behaves as a static class.
     */

public abstract class Utilities
    {
        // prevent inheritance
        private Utilities()
        {
        }
    // ... all your static methods here
        public static Person convert(string) {...}
    }
```

This class cannot be inherited (like final because although abstract it has a private constuctor), cannot be instantiated (like static because abstract) so only static methods in it can be called.