# How are static arrays stored in Java memory?

Tags: java, c, arrays, memory, static

So in a language like C, memory is separated into 5 different parts: OS Kernel, text segment, static memory, dynamic memory, and the stack. Something like this:

[image: Memory Layout]

If we declared a static array in C, you had to specify it's size beforehand after that would be fixed forevermore. The program would allocate enough memory for the array and stick it in the static data segment as expected.

However I noticed that in Java, you could do something like this:

```
public class Test {
        static int[] a = new int[1];

        public static void main( String[] args ) {
                a = new int[2];
        }
}
```

and everything would work as you'd expect. My question is, why does this work in Java?

EDIT: So the consensus is that an `int[]` in Java is acts more similarly to an `int*` in C. So as a follow up question, is there any way to allocate arrays in static memory in Java (if no, why not)? Wouldn't this provide quicker access to such arrays?
EDIT2: ^ this is in a new question now: [Where are static class variables stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655338/where-are-static-class-variables-stored-in-memory)

Comment: Actually the shown model is not even generally true for C. It may be true for your usual desktop, but the memory model in C is pretty simple and generous. C on an embedded system will look totally different.

Comment: @tskuzzy: you should ask your follow-up question as another question to disambiguate the answers below.

Comment: I don't believe that "in a language like C memory is separated". The language standard is very careful not to prescribe any memory implementation details. Also, your picture only has three named segments but you claim there are five.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Well it's not "separated" per se. But there are definitely different memory regions. I'm not sure what the standard says but I think most computers follow a similar memory layout to the one described. "Reserved" == "OS Kernel", and I guess they combined the text segment with the static data segment in the picture.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In java any time you use the word `new`, memory for that object is allocated on the heap and a reference is returned. This is also true for arrays. The `int[] a` is just the reference to `new int[1]`. When you do `new int[2]`, a new array is allocated and pointed to a. The old array will be garbage collected when needed.

Answer (score 17):

The value of `a` is just a reference to an object. The array creation expression (`new int[2]`) creates a *new* object of the right size, and assigns a reference to `a`.

Note that `static` in Java is fairly separate to `static` in C. In Java it just means "related to the type rather than to any particular instance of the type".

Comment: +1, for a deeper look at C's `static` vs Java's `static` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728534/whats-the-equivalent-of-cs-static-keyword-in-java

Answer (score 6):

You are creating a new array, not modifying the old one.  The new array will get its own space and the old one will be garbage-collected (so long as nobody else holds a reference to it).

Answer (score 4):

I assume when you're referring to "static memory" you're referring to the heap.  In Java, the heap serves a similar purpose to the "static data segment" you mentioned.  The heap is where most objects are allocated, including arrays.  The stack, on the other hand, is where objects that are used only during the life of a single method are placed.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you've merely asked that a strongly typed reference to an array be stored statically for the class `Test`. You can change what `a` refers to at runtime, which includes changing the *size*. This would be the C equivalent of a static storage of an `int*`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a `static` variable exists as part of the class object. Think of it as an instance variable for the class itself. In your example, `a` is a reference variable, which refers to some array (or no array at all, if it is `null`), but the array itself is allocated as all arrays are in Java: off the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Static has a different meaning in Java. In Java when you declare a variable as static it is a class variable and not an instance variable.