# Java default variable values

Tags: java, variables

In C a static variable or a variable in a file scope is initialized to 0 when declared and a variable declared in a function that is not initialized has random data. Does this happen in Java too somehow?

Note: I refer only to primitive types not objects.

Comment: Difference between static in java and c. Just so you know there is a difference :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728534/whats-the-equivalent-of-cs-static-keyword-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Yes java also has default values for primitive data types.
Default Value (for fields)

- byte     :    0
- short    :    0
- int      :    0
- long.    :    0L
- float    :    0.0f
- double   :    0.0d
- char     :    ‘u0000’
- boolean  : false
- String (or any object)   :  null

Comment: I know, but does this happen everywhere or it does not apply to variables declared inside a function like in C?